# Can a magic sysreq key combo run a script?

Tags: linux, magic-sysrq

I'm experiencing system hangs which seem to correlate with high RAM usage levels (though swap is mostly unused).

I'd like to be able to kill thunderbird and other memory hogs via a script with a magic sysreq combo.

Is there any way of running a script via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysReq</kbd>?

Comment: You might be interested by the [perf tools](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools) to help you investigate what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook a script into Alt+SysRq if you modify the kernel sources. The Alt+SysRq handling is defined in `drivers/tty/sysrq.c`. For instance, Alt+SysRq+f calls the `sysrq_handle_moom()` function that schedules a call of `out_of_memory()` to kill a process.

```
static void moom_callback(struct work_struct *ignored)
{
    /* ... */
    if (!out_of_memory(&oc))
    /* ... */
}

static DECLARE_WORK(moom_work, moom_callback);

static void sysrq_handle_moom(int key)
{
        schedule_work(&moom_work);
}
static struct sysrq_key_op sysrq_moom_op = {
        .handler        = sysrq_handle_moom,
        .help_msg       = "memory-full-oom-kill(f)",
        .action_msg     = "Manual OOM execution",
        .enable_mask    = SYSRQ_ENABLE_SIGNAL,
};
```

Comment: I have no idea how that works, but I would guess that forking (which is probably neccessary to spawn a script) is not guaranteed to succeed under the kind of circumstances where Alt+SysRq is typically used, so changing the kernel for this might be a lot of work for nothing.

Comment: I get a load average of approx 100, but things still w...o...r...k.......